# No such file (header file) error

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin

I want to include a header file.  I am working in a C++ environment, (C++11, Windows OS, Netbeans 7.3.1 IDE, Cygwin_4.x tool collection).  I do not know how I setup the environment/IDE (I did it 6 months ago).  I do not understand the fundamentals of the C++ build process or Cygwin related issues either, so I might have to fill in the gaps with some other references/documentation (on what specifically, I'm not sure).

My ultimate objective is to be able to include header files using a syntax that does not require the full file path.  I want to write something terse, like:

```
#include "src\stuff\blah.h"  //or even better:  #include "blah.h"
```

The only way I can get my program to compile at all is by using the full file path, like this:

```
#include "C:\NetBeansProjects\Project1\src\stuff\blah.h"
```

And, I can only compile once using the full path.  If I try to rebuild, it will bomb with the `*** multiple target patterns.  Stop.` error.  There are workarounds for this error; those being either 1) deleting the `build` and `dist` folders between each rebuild (yikes?), or 2) [following this 16 step setup process](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/cpp-setup-instructions.html#mingw).

I do not want to follow either of those workarounds because they do not appear to deliver what I want.  How can I setup my environment to achieve what I want...of being able to include header files without using full paths?

Comment: The compiler is most likely searching for include files starting from the file that is being compiled. Is the source code you are trying to compile in "src"? If so, the include should be `#include "stuff/blah.h"`. Also note the forward slashes.

Comment: I've never used netbeans, but I'd be shocked if there wasn't a way to add directories to the include search path. If many (or all) of your include files are in the same place, that's the way to go.

Comment: @DanielKO - Everything (all .cc and .h files) in the project are under the "src" directory, but then they are further sorted using subdirectories (ex. stuff).  In this particular case, I have a file in one subdirectory (src/stuff) trying to include a file from another subdirectory (src/morestuff).  Also, the forward slashes are not helping (error = `stuff/blah.h - no such file or directory`).

Comment: @jerry - I have tried wrestling with the `Tools >> Options >> Code Assistance >> C++ Compiler` options.  That has the "include directories" to which I believe you are referring.  I cannot figure out the magic solution there either.  The interface seems to enforce backslashes only (not slashes "/") in the paths, for whatever that is worth.

Comment: Then you need to walk up the path: `#include "../morestuff/blah"`. Forward slashes are fine everywhere, except when interacting with MS-DOS and explorer.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [DanielKO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1484212/danielko) for this answer.

In my case, I was able to include with the syntax:

```
#include "../stuff/blah.h"
```

I did not have to configure anything under the "Code Assistance" section for the C++ compiler.

All of my code is under "src" as the parent directory in my NetBeans project.  It seems that the full path of the file is not required, and the only directory that must be referenced is the lowest level subdirectory (in my case, "stuff").

Answer (score 1):

In NetBeans I've added the path to the list of libraries:

1. Go to Properties->Select C++->Select 'include libraries'->'Add'
   Now: Add the path of the project folder with option "absolute"
2. Go to Properties->Select C++->Select 'Additional library directories'->'Add'
   Now: Add the path of the project folder with option "absolute"

It's very obscure to me why the project doesn't recognize "own" header files.